# Right Detail Style in UITableView Controller not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode5

I'm reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0097N8XBE) that teaches non-programers how to create iOS App. It's a step by step book.

To create the App, we use Xcode. And on one of the steps, on the storyboard, we have to add a cell in the table view controller and use "Right Detail" Style. And here where my problem is.

When I select the Right Detail Style, nothing happens. I cannot add any data in the cell or type anything. The content of the table is static (not sure if that's relevant).

However, when I run the simulator, the cell would show the default text of the cell, which are Title and Detail.

I don't have this problem with the others styles (the Basic, Left Detail and Subtitle).

Here is a screenshot that might help explaining it more:

[image]

Bear in mind I know nothing about programming.
This is my first programming attempt. So please be gentle :D. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn how to code..
Double click on the title and detail labels in your cell, you will be allowed to edit them
OR
got to the document outline and select them from there to edit them